# How to store input from echo in arrays in C

Tags: c

If I were to type in `echo "1001" | ./test` in the terminal.

and `test` takes "1001" and stores it into a array, how would I do that?

In `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()  {
  int  c, i, j;

  int a[4];
  while(c = (getchar() != EOF)) {
    a[i++] = c;
  }
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++ {
    printf("%d", a[j]);
  }
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please note that it is generally not very help to say "It's not working".  You should be explicit about the behaviour you are seeing.  In this case, you are (should be) getting a number of Control-A characters printed — whether you can see them or not.  As the answers have noted, you have issues with `i` uninitialized, the condition in the `while` loop (which is what stores Control-A in the `c` and hence in the string), buffer overflow, and incorrect print format.

Comment: OK; ignore the `printf()` format comment — I misread the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that this program works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int  c, i = 0, j;

  int a[4];
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && i < 4)
  {
    a[i++] = c;
  }

  for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    printf("%c", a[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");  // Be nice to non-windows users :)

  return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of changes from your original program.  Initialisation of `i`, putting a limit on the number of characters read, outputting only 4 characters (`j < 4`) and fixing a bit of your syntax (missing brackets and `int main(int argc, char** argv)`).  Oh, and `(c = getchar()) != EOF` since your first want to store your character and then do the comparison.

I also changed `%d` to `%c` so that the characters are printed, you could change this back if you want, it depends what you actually want the program to produce.

Comment: +1: Good...it would be sensible (at least on non-Windows machines) to end the output with a newline.  But you picked on the key points — `i = 0`, the `while` condition, buffer overflow, incorrect print format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize `i` to 0.
2. In your code:

   ```
   c = (getchar() != EOF)
   ```

   means c is a boolean value rather than the char you get from input. Change it to:

   ```
   (c = getchar()) != EOF
   ```

Comment: Two good points; you missed on (3) there are 5 characters in the data before EOF so you have a buffer overflow and (4) you can't print a string using `%d` and (5) if you change the `%d` to `%s` you've not got a null terminated string (so you need at least 6 characters in the array and explicit null termination, or at least 5 characters and `%.5s` to include the newline in the output).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks for the revision. :P

Comment: Ignore the comment about `printf()` format; I misread the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why read char by char? Just read the line.

```
char line[50];
fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
// line now contains "1001\n". You can chop off the \n with the following line:
line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `i` variable, so it's garbage. Also, the condition should be `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Comment: As I noted to someone else — two good points; you missed on (3) there are 5 characters in the data before EOF so you have a buffer overflow and (4) you can't print a string using `%d` and (5) if you change the `%d` to `%s` you've not got a null terminated string (so you need at least 6 characters in the array and explicit null termination, or at least 5 characters and `%.5s` to include the newline in the output).

Comment: Well, in this very specific input data - surely. On other cases, we can find many many other potential problems, but i don't believe we should. But i don't get your meaning of %s in this context - it's not a string, it's int array.

Comment: I can't read, it seems; I am so used to reading into `int` and then copying to `char` with `getchar()` that I didn't notice what it's actually up to...my (very) bad.